# Обозначение национальностей

Tags: грамотная-речь

Помните "Казачью колыбельную" М.Ю. Лермонтова?

*По камням струится Терек,

   Плещет мутный вал;

Злой чечен ползет на берег,

   Точит свой кинжал;

Но отец твой старый воин,

   Закален в бою:

Спи, малютка, будь спокоен,

   Баюшки-баю.*

Так вот, я о слово "чечен". Сейчас чаще можно услышать форму "чеченец", но при этом мы говорим, например, "грузин", а не, пардон, "грузинец".))) Афган - это чаще порода борзой собаки, нежели национальность, хоть, в принципе, разницы нет, потому что, к примеру, кавказскую овчарку называют просто кавказец.
Если честно, я запутался. Есть ли тут какая-то закономерность?

Answer (score 2):

У "грузина" уже есть прекрасный суффикс "-ин-" (указывающий на принадлежность к группе).
А, вот, "чеченец" обходится суффиксом "-ец-" (указывающим, почему-то, на индивидуальный признак)...

Видимо, дело в количестве. Когда возникло слово "грузин" ("армянин", "татарин"...), русские контактировали с достаточным количеством представителей данной этносоциальной группы, чтоб воспринимать их именно как группу (ср. "дворянин", "селянин", "хуторянин"), а, вот, "чеченцам" ("афганцам", "испанцам"..) повезло меньше - их воспринимали исключительно как отдельные личности, наделённые общим признаком (ср. "мудрец", "удалец", "юнец").

Answer (score 1):

чечен, -а (устар. к чеченец) [Gramota.ru](http://dic.gramota.ru/search.php?word=%F7%E5%F7%E5%ED&all=x&lop=&gorb=&efr=&zar=&ag=&ab=&el=&lv=&az=&pe=&sin)

[Чечен](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=429.4KrgA9DDUWqg2Ufy51cPhlDLnBi-U9y3E_Z_UtKIFLGqvXNT5XVusPJhQZxYikmmDEWpWbj3j5xfQ8gBCWQ-eFXF_nd3RU40Q0tGfbX6zTMFK3g6BQcn5HZVajUoYyHpYzpnSkoTb6Np00cJAtlBUHreJs8pNuP0y8Gg69AmaxA.09ad65d8f9b88a9e368c9d7318303d072a4f45b9&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9Xu2OK3FawXhsm5LyVOUy4y8dk2IM6mfrUGX6uo6LL7IRVcmHz7jL3efIHRPy0TkQj5p4hJd03GmcPdtCpxuLTpOyh1Qrj8XlT05I-PNoo91V8FkY-5notieayan5L7R0tldCqnqKzWhCIG_yy6fXiAhvQbUMghFDX2JwZFOWkSuFHXTNiAndUfW&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxbzRFMDJoV2pkYUVwSU5vbXQyd3FaRmc5OTltekFzdnZqRm1ROGlCbzlJbkc2XzZCTzJwcVYtLUFhM2VnN1BuYVItY3V2VDhkb3VVS2dJUExISkg5S3ZPREZpdzBHdUVwUQ&b64e=2&sign=af79a57067b11ba5c100d89e354fc470&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1409141364305&mc=4.3298851366343705)